# Select according to position and additional data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables that contain image data for a product. This is exactly the data I have to work with. Note that the thumbnail image for this product ID `10` is in the `thumbnail` table and only further identified by its file name.

1. `images`: has image file names.

   ```
   id | product_id |    file
   -----------------------------
   1  |     10     | image1.jpg
   2  |     10     | image2.jpg
   3  |     10     | image3.jpg
   ```
2. `positions`: has positions of the images (`id` is same as `images`).

   ```
   id | position
   --------------
   1  |    1
   2  |    2
   3  |    3
   ```
3. `thumbnail`: has thumbnail (one per product).

   ```
   product_id |   file
   -----------------------
       10     | image3.jpg
   ```

I'm looking to write the most optimum query that will get me the `file`s in the `position` `ASC` order, but with the `thumbnail` image always first regardless of its position value. So, I'm looking to get..

```
image3.jpg
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
```

I'm stuck trying to write this into a single query (if possible). I can run two queries an do a `UNION` and get what I need. Any better idea?

Comment: Why is position in a separate table?

Comment: @Strawberry, because there are different positions that can be set based on the store you're in. I've removed store information from this to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am interpreting the use of position correctly, I would imagine something like this should work.

```
SELECT i.file
FROM images AS i 
INNER JOIN positions AS p ON i.id = p.id
LEFT JOIN thumbnail AS t ON i.product_id = t.product_id AND i.file = t.file
WHERE i.product_id = ?
ORDER BY (t.product_id IS NULL), p.position
;
```

*(t.product_id IS NULL)* is basically an "is not thumbnail" check; since false orders earlier, the image that is **not** "not the thumbnail" will be first.

Comment: Superb! I did not know you can do `IS NULL` ordering!

Comment: @musicliftsme _Generally speaking_, anything you can do in the select, you can do in the order. There is little difference between what I posted and `SELECT i.file, t.product_id IS NULL AS notThumb FROM .... ORDER BY notThumb, ...`

Comment: I'm wondering why the `IS NULL` ordering places the thumbnail (which is not null for `t.product_id`) first?

Comment: @musicliftsme `t.product_id IS NULL` is true for non-thumbnails; true(1) gets ordered after false(0). To make things simpler, you could do something like this instead `SELECT i.file, t.product_id IS NOT NULL AS isThumbnail ... ORDER BY IF(isThumbnail, 0, 1), p.position`... but it might be a little slower.

Answer (score 0):

[Union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) is your friend here, so long as position always starts at > 0 and you set the thumbnail image to position 0

```
SELECT [file]
FROM 
(
SELECT [file], 0 As position FROM thumbnail
UNION SELECT [file], position FROM images i 
    INNER JOIN positions p 
        ON i.id = p.id
    WHERE i.[file] NOT IN (SELECT [file] FROM thumbnail)
) DATA
ORDER BY DATA.position
```